# Why is Webmaster Tools reporting missing author/ updated when the markup exists?

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, structured-data

Google Webmaster Tools is reporting Structured Data > hentry errors for my Wordpress site (Divi theme)

```
Missing: author
Missing: updated
```

When I check the page with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, it contains the following markup

```
<p class="post-meta">
  <span class="author vcard">
    <a href="http://path/to/autor/profile" rel="author">Author Name</a>
  </span>
  <span class="published">Dec 1, 2016</span>
</p>
```

I have two questions:

1. What is wrong with this markup that is preventing the hentry author and
   updated attributes from being detected? (or, where is a link to up-to-date markup requirements, Google searching reveals many variations).
2. The page also contains complete and error free JSON-LD structured
   data. Are there any conflicts/ issues with having two structured
   data formats on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

1) I would recommend to use Microdata or JSON-LD to describe your objects

2) It is hard to make a proposition without seeing that. Also, it is not understandable what object you tries to describe.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nick. The markup describes an Article. What I'm wondering is, doesn't `vCard` + `rel=author` describe the author? And doesn't the `published` tag describe when the article was updated. Based on my understanding of the standard, the markup above correctly identifies these elements. But perhaps I've misunderstood the standard?

Comment: And agree I would prefer to use JSON-LD, and have added this manually. However the theme I'm using has the hentry markup. Are there likely to be conflicts if using two SD specifications on the same page?

Comment: Andy, I would say this "vcard" is something from microformats, as I remember.. Yes, supports this, but I don't think they will support this for a while. I would recommend to switch to other formats.
So, If you want Google only - use JSON-LD, if you need the support of Google and Bing - use microdata.
Thanks.